# How to Implement Context Api in material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, material-ui

I am trying to pass a property using context API in my components. I am getting the following typescript error.

Property 'value' does not exist on type 'String'

I am creating the context using

```
export const TimeZoneContext = createContext("timeZone");
```

Then providing the value in my return for the component as

```
<TimeZoneContext.Provider value="timeZone" />
```

I am consuming the value in another component's return statement using the following statement

```
 <TimeZoneContext.Consumer>
        {({ value }) => (
          <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>{value}</TableCell>
        )}
      </TimeZoneContext.Consumer>
```

Please feel to ask for any more information needed. Thanks. How is implementing nested context api different than the simple one. I think the problem is that the components in provider and consumer do not share a relation. Thanks

Comment: Hopefully it helps. https://www.toptal.com/react/react-context-api

Comment: @Garry I am following the documentation but no help yet. I cannot retrieve the value in Consumer.

Comment: Posting a sandboxcode mimicking what I am presently doing in the code. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ttz6x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the useContext hook to retrieve the value.

Here is your code modified

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-sb27x?fontsize=14

```
export const TimeZoneContext = createContext("timeZone"); 

ReactDOM.render( <TimeZoneContext.Provider value="PST"><App/> </TimeZoneContext.Provider>, 
                 document.querySelector('#root'));

//In your App.js you should see value 'PST'
const context = useContext(TimeZoneContext);

// You can use value in the context in className
<Table className={classes[context]}> 
// Use value in TableCell
<TableCell>{context}</TableCell>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned. The provider and consumer are in different component structure not connected via a parent. So importing App will not work.

Comment: I might have to update context using Nested Component https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component